# iPhone Application is not opened next day in device why?

Tags: iphone

I am a newbie in iPhone Development.I developed an iPhone Application and installed this application on the device in that time it's working fine but on the next day it's not working this application saved last build setup in device

Comment: Connect your device to Mac, Launch Go to Organizer in XCode then Device Console. See info OS writes to console about your App.

Comment: I recieved an email from apple about their fix for some bad certificates that had been going around.  It sounds like yours expired.  I know mine did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that is your developer certificate is expired or not.I think expired that's why you are facing this problem.

Comment: it's valid.next day without connect to system it can work?

Comment: I think you should delete the app from your iPhone and reload the app from your builder.

Comment: after remove the connection from mac system and switch off the  ipad device then switch on then my application is not opend why?

Comment: is your application being install in you iPhone?